# Проблемы с чтением файла через javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Есть функция, где я пытаюсь записать в переменную данные текстового файла с сервера

```js
function loadModel(){
 
 var cookiePath = readCookie('modelID');
 var modelPath = "../modelbase/php_base/models/"+cookiePath+".zedit";
 
 var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", modelPath, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var modelText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(modelText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Но при попытке считывания в консоль получаю предупреждение (на строке rawFile.open...):

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Есть ли какой-то способ получить данные из нужного файла?

Comment: Примите тогда ответ пожалуйста) Предвижу что скоро начнутся проблемы с тем как обработать результат асинхронного запроса. Когда начнутся - поищите здесь внимательно, вопросы про асинхронность здесь задают раз в день

Comment: Сейчас уже исправил, пока все работает беспроблемно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предупреждение говорит вам:

> "Вы пытаетесь отправить синхронный xhr запрос. Отправлять синхронные
>   запросы больше не модно, потому что юзерам не нравится ждать."

За синхронность/асинхронность `xhr` отвечает третий параметр функции `xhr.open`.
Можно поставить его в `true` или вообще убрать (он `true` по умолчанию).